# MinGW gcc C compiled program detected as virus by avast

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, trojan

I have readed a lot of people with the same problem but the most of them are Windows Defender, in my case it only happens with avast(free version) and it detects this simple hello program compiled version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Name: ");
    char name[20];
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

as "Win32:TrojanX-gen[Trj]" but some days ago i made another program and ran it into notepad++ console using cmd and nothing happened, is it a problem with avast or is it my pc?

Thank you.

Comment: So what is detected as a virus - the compiler or the compiled program?

Comment: the compiled program

Comment: Ya, I need to disable my scanner when compiling on Windows. They're all on a hair-trigger.

Comment: Looks like some stupid false positive. Sure, you can take the code and disassemble it and see if it is legit, but I would say it is. Just add your working directory to exceptions

Comment: i saw someone saying that it could also be because a malware injecting a virus in my program but avast keep saying that there is no malware in my pc

Comment: just in case how could i dissasemble the program?

Comment: @DavidRanieri I think it won't yield a valid test. I meant to disassemble the final executable - as this is where the virus can be injected

Comment: if i use the .exe program in a virtual machine it could show me if there is any virus in it?